# After pyinstaller--onefile creates the exe, the wav file in the program only plays on the computer that the exe file was created on

Tags: windows, pyinstaller

< The exe file created by pyinstaller--onefile DOES play the wave file except when I copy the
exe program to other windows 10 computers, I will only hear a 'beep' not the wave file. My question is,
doesn't pyinstaller bundle all that is needed to run the stand-alone program?  I use Pycharm with
Python38. Pyinstaller is up to date>

```
'''
#import simpleaudio as sa
#from playsound import playsound
import winsound
from chart import chart
from BreakerZones import BreakerZones
import time
import sys
import colorama
import yaml  # to print the nested_lookup results(n) on separate lines
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup, get_all_keys # importing 2 items from nested_lookup
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import os

colorama.init(autoreset=True)  # If you don't want to print Style.RESET_ALL all the time,
                               # reset automatically after each print statement with True
print(colorama.ansi.clear_screen())

print('\n'*4)  # prints a newline 4 times


print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                             Arriving-' + Fore.GREEN + '    *** BREAKERVILLE USA ***')


def main():

    print('\n' * 2)
    print(Fore.BLUE + '   Breaker Numbers and Zones')

    k = get_all_keys(BreakerZones)
    # raw amount of keys even repeats , has quotes

    new_l = []                                         # eliminate extra repeating nested keys
    for e in k:                                        # has quotes
        if e not in new_l and sorted(e) not in new_l:  #
            new_l.append(e)                            #
    print()

    new_l.sort()  # make alphabetical
    newer_l = ('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, new_l)).strip("' ,"))  # remove ['%s'] brackets so they don't show up when run
    print(' ', yaml.dump(newer_l, default_flow_style=False))    #  strip("' ,")  or will see leading "' ," in output

    print(Fore.BLUE + '   ENTER A BREAKER # OR ZONE', Fore.GREEN + ': ', end='')
    i = input().strip().lower()  # these lines is workaround for the colorama
    print()              # user input() issue of 'code' appearing in screen output

    if i in k:
        n = (nested_lookup(i, BreakerZones, wild=False, with_keys=False))   # wild=True means key not case sensitive,
        print(yaml.dump(n, default_flow_style=False))                       # 'with_keys' returns values + keys also
        # for key, value in n.items():     eliminated by using yaml
        #    print(key, '--', value)       eliminated by using yaml
    else:
        print(Fore.YELLOW + ' Typo,' + Fore.GREEN + ' try again')
        main()

    print()

    print(Fore.GREEN + '           Continue? Y or N: C for breaker chart : ', end='')  # see comments ENTER A BREAKER
    ans = input().strip().lower()      # strip() removes any spaces before or after user input

    if ans == 'c':
        chart()
        print()
        print(Fore.GREEN + '           Continue? Y or N : ', end='')
        ans = input().strip().lower()             # strip() removes any spaces before or after user input
        if ans == 'y':                            # shorter version 'continue Y or N' after printing breaker chart
            main()
        else:
            print()
            print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                            Departing -' + Fore.GREEN + '   *** BREAKERVILLE ***')
        filename = os.path.join(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))),
                                'train_whistle.wav')
        #filename = 'C:/Users/oseda/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/train_whistle.wav'
        winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        time.sleep(2) # delay to exit program
        sys.exit()

    elif ans != 'y':

        print()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + '                            Good Day -' + Fore.GREEN + '   *** BREAKERVILLE ***')

        filename = os.path.join(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))),
                                'train_whistle.wav')
        #filename = 'C:/Users/oseda/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/train_whistle.wav'
        winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        time.sleep(2)  # delay to exit program

        sys.exit()

    else:
        main()


main()
'''
```

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information This link has a nice ' test code' to check whether the app I'm using is 'bundled' or 'source'. Seems like a good test for my listed problem. When I run this in my script I get:  module 'sys' has no attribute 'frozen'.

Comment: ok I just figured out that I had to run that test by using Pyinstaller. Brilliant on my part. I do see the results 'running in a Pyinstaller bundle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Replace

```
filename = 'C:/Users/oseda/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/train_whistle.wav'
```

with

```
filename = os.path.join(getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))),'train_whistle.wav')
```

2. Copy C:/Users/oseda/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/train_whistle.wav in the same folder as your script
3. add `--add-data "train_whistle.wav;."` to your pyinstaller build command

Comment: 'pyinstaller --onefile -add-data "train_whistle.wav;." BreakerVille.wav' I see the error: argument -d/--debug: invalid choice: 'd-data (choose from 'all', 'imports', 'bootloader', 'noarchive')

Comment: 'pyinstaller --onefile -add-data "train_whistle.wav;." --add-data 'BreakerVille.wav;.' yourscript.py is the correct syntax. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Comment: To be clearer, the program works well with the replaced line,  filename=...., I just get the error when using pyinstaller.

Comment: ' pyinstaller --onefile -add-data "train_whistle.wav;."BreakerVille.py" '

Comment: There was a typo in my solution (now edited): the correct command is pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "train_whistle.wav;." BreakerVille.py"

Comment: No " at the end

Comment: Much Thanks Eric. It works great now. I'll spend some time understanding the code you provided . Paul